How efficient is ICP-MS at atomizing molecules?
I have read that the amount of ionization of a species in ICP-MS can be estimated with the Saha equation. But I have not been able to find a good source talking about how efficiently molecules are atomized in the plasma. Is it basically 100% for every molecule? I am mainly curious about metal oxides.

Good question but too generic. How can one make a sweeping statement about all the metals in the periodic table (80+)? Maybe you can look up bond dissociation energies of a certain metal oxide and use thermodynamics to see what fraction will be dissociated from bond dissociation energies. Most metal oxides will not survive plasma temperature and secondly, argon plasma will not promote oxides. It is rich in electrons (reducing) and non-oxidative. No oxygen there. It is not a flame. Post this question in physics rather than chemistry (delete/migrate there).
